# rotation driven by vertex z value - ocean modifier

Tags: animation, drivers, ocean-simulation

I would like to be able to drive the rotation of a boat by the z value of a surface vertex of a plane with ocean modifier on it.

Is there a way to access to this data without Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an empty, select it and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select your plane. Enter edit mode and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. This will parent you empty to the vertex, so the empties location will match that of the vertex.

[image]

To make this work with the ocean modifier. Make a new object, set it to shrink wrap the plane with your ocean modifier, and then make it a single vertex. Use the above parenting technique to attach you empty to the vertex.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I've tried this solution, and also a shrinkwrap constraint, but the empty is not affected by the ocean modifier, so it isn't useful for my purpose.

Comment: Ah you should have specified that....

Comment: @joshsanfelici Updated, now works